# WP Advanced custom field value in query posts array

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need to put an advanced custom field value (category number) from page to query_posts array. Is it somehow possible?

On a single page I'm trying to show posts from category, which number is value of this custom field.

Ideal and of course non-functional case:

```
query_posts(array('category__and'=>array( the_field("category"); ,99), 'posts_per_page'=>6));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_field()` *displays* a meta value. You'll want to use [`get_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) (which *returns* a meta value) instead:

```
query_posts(array('category__and'=>array( get_field("category"); ,99), 'posts_per_page'=>6));
```

In somewhat unrelated news, you should really consider [avoiding the use of `query_posts`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

Comment: It works perfect, thanks a lot! And thanks for the tip aswell.